# Adding tags dynamically to HTML at the right place

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Somewhere in the HTML file we have this:

```
<script SRC="story_content/user.js" TYPE="text/javascript"></script>
```

What if we want to dynamically (Javascript is preferred JQuery is accepted) add another script tag or CSS link right after it.

Explanation: We need to select the script tag by `SRC` and we need to add the tags after the script tag.

Here is the tags we need to add after the script tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../sources/main.min.css" data-noprefix />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="html5/data/css/output.min.css" data-noprefix />
<script data-main="app/scripts/init.generated" src="../../../sources/app.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) + [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Comment: And how can we select the tag by src?! when we have no id or class...

Comment: `document.querySelector('[src="story_content/user.js"]')`

Comment: How the hell you know these stuff??????? Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use query selector to acheive the target in pure js like:

```
var source_name = "story_content/user.js"              // path of file

var add_to = document.querySelector(`script[src=${source_name}]`);
```

Once, add_to is store, you should be able to add the tag, like:

```
var to_be_added_tag = document.CreateElement("script");
to_be_added_tag.setAttribute("src", src_path_of_your_file); // src_path_of_your_file is variable, value of src attribute

add_to.after(to_be_added_tag);
```

*Note:- `after` is used to add element after some node. [refs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/after)

Comment: how will you add a new tag after selection ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer plus one ... And how to select href? I used `const selectMainMinCSS = document.querySelector('[href="html5/lib/stylesheets/main.min.css"]');` but it returns null!

Comment: It might be returning null cos there might be no tag with href of that value. Check the spelling!!! Also try: ```document.querySelector('link[href="html5/lib/stylesheets/main.min.css"]')```

Comment: Yeah, The page or the tag was not loaded when I tried to select it....